# SDL Web 8.5 Topology manager UNABLE TO LOAD PUBLICATION MAPPINGS. could not connect to topology manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8.5, topology-manager

We are upgrading from Tridion 2013 SP1 to Tridion 8.5 using Legacy. After that, we will rewrite the templates from VB to .Net and migrate to 9.1 and sure we could go for 9.1 at once. 
But the cost and project needs are the key reason to go for 8.5 first. That said we don't want to use topology manager for publishing but when installing 8.5 it needs the Topology database. so we have the database and the install using legacy option worked fine. everything is working and we can publish it. But when we do properties on a publication and go to the publishing tab, we get an error: UNABLE TO LOAD PUBLICATION MAPPINGS / could not connect to topology manager. In the event log, we end up with the following errors:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   The network path was not found Component:
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Service Errorcode: 0 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.RdbmsDataSession.GetConnection()
>   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MsSql.MsSqlDataSession.BuilDbCommand(String
>   comandName) at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.RdbmsDataSession.Get[T](String
>   entityName, Int64 version) at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.CachedEntitySet`1.EnsureUpToDate()
>   at Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.CachedEntitySet`1.GetAll() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.Storage.StorageManager.GetEntitySet[T]()
>   at Tridion.TopologyManager.TopologyItem`1.GetList() at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Get()
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: Welcome to Tridionstackexchange Roel!, The error messages look like SQL connection issue, Is that Topology database running in the same database server as CMS DB? could you double-check that topology manager database accessible on CMS server.

Comment: Refer to this link to solve the connection issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in the web.config of the topology manager the old domain name was still used for the user credentials after encrypting the config and changing the setting things work like a charm. the [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-A7B26918-1A7B-4AE8-A6A6-16B82C893CC0.xml&docid=GUID-A7B26918-1A7B-4AE8-A6A6-16B82C893CC0&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A7B26918-1A7B-4AE8-A6A6-16B82C893CC0) is a bit confusing on doing this encryption, so for those who want to know the below lines work:

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"`

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "database" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web" -prov TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider`

Comment: Glad that you have figured it out. Please accept the answer so the question becomes closed.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indeed an SQL connection problem.

To solve the SQL connection problem:

1. Make sure SQL Server Service is running
2. If a named instance, make sure SQL Server browser service is running
3. Make sure SQL Server is configured to allowed remote connections
4. Test port connectivity using **TELNET** or PowerShell to the server and port (from step from the client CMS machine.
   For example

   - Telnet sql-server-name 1433
   - or PowerShell:

> 1433 | % { echo ((new-object
>       Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServerName",$*)) "server
>       listening on TCP port $*" }

5. Check firewall settings if step 4 or 5 connectivity test fails

I hope it helps.

Comment: Tried all off that, and it all seems to be okay.